# UICollectionView dataSource and delegate cause termination of app

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently studying swift `CollectionView`, I followed each step of the tutorial but somehow my app ends up being terminated with this error

[image: this is the error message]

Disconnect the dateSource and delegate seems can stop it from crashing but it ends up having nothing in the collection view. Any hints would be appreciated:)

this is my `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    struct Item {
        var title:String
        var Image:String
        var price:Double
    }

    let items:[Item] = [Item(title: "Mario Kart", Image: "Mario", price: 5), Item(title: "Car", Image: "Car", price: 6), Item(title: "Doll", Image: "Doll", price: 3)]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: items[indexPath.row].Image)
        cell.myPrice.text = String(items[indexPath.row].price)
        cell.myTitle.text = String(items[indexPath.row].title)
        return cell
    }


}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTitle: UILabel!
}
```

[image: This is my storyboard]

Comment: *UPDATE!* it was me forgotten connecting the storyboard and the class :(((((( thank to everyone for the reply and help

Answer (score -1):

Please make an IBOutlet connection to collectionView. 
Then add the

```
collectionView.delegate=self
collectionView.datasource=self
```

lines inside `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Thanks for replying Arun, but it won't let me drop the connection, I guess it could be my viewController doesn't extend to collectionView, do you have any solution?

Comment: check reuseidentifier inside storyboard, its working fine my side.

Comment: @ArunSairam Your current answer isn't correct and the question was closed as a duplicate. It would be best to delete your answer.